# Page load flickers on PhoneGap iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova

My **PhoneGap** application uses slide in and slide out animations using entirely CSS animations.

You can find the project I based my app on [here](http://c2prods.com/2013/cloning-the-ui-of-ios-7-with-html-css-and-javascript/#comment-810).

As you can see from the demo the slide transition is quite smooth, but as soon as I add images, after the new page is loaded it flickers/blinks for a fraction of second. The interesting thing is that all the UI elements are shown on screen and then the flickers occurs. More, sometimes the page scrolling becomes buggy and it doesn't let me scroll to the bottom of the page where my images are.

I cached the images using CSS to improve image load but again no luck.
I also found on different blogs about a similar issue on JQ mobile and tried adding without luck:

```
    webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

You don't know how much I appreciate your help I spent my whole Saturday trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of fiddling I realized that the issue was because of the scrolling mechanism and fixed header which are poorly supported by -webkit browser. I am now using iscroll 5 and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

it is due to you JS files
if you load the more js file on html page then it will take time you will find the filck in phonegap application
when you develop application in phonegap then try to use single page architecture to develop application that must be the better option
even i am suffer this problem.

Comment: That's interesting! Have you found any solution? I thought it was related to touch scrolling and fixed header...

Comment: if you are agree with my answer the please like my Answer.for best solution you have to make app that is based on the single page architecture